# Personal hotspot hosts count incorrect on iPhone

Tags: internet-sharing, iphone, tethering

Sometimes when I share my Internet network from my iPhone 6 Plus to other devices via Wi-Fi, the status bar shows '3 connections' when I really know that I only have 2 connections: sometimes I get one phantom connection to my iPhone (I guess) via Personal Hotspot.

Why does this occur and how can I prevent it?

Comment: When you have hotspot turned on, is your phone connected via USB to your computer?

Comment: No, It's not USB connected. Only wifi.

Comment: Right - but is the phone connected to a computer USB port regardless, such as to charge or sync? Or, is it not plugged in at all?

Comment: It's not plugged....

Comment: If I have my MacBook Pro using my iPhone as a hotspot, and plug that iPhone into that Mac, then the count goes up from 1 to 2, even though that Mac is already using that same hotspot.  It's as if the USB connection is a separate host utilizing the hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed if your phone is connected to the computer not necessarily in order to sync, it counts it up.  You can easily check by looking at the blue bar with the count on it, unplugging the phone and waiting for the change. Then plug it back in.  It confused me as well because I plug my phone onto a desk stand for charging so I hadnt noticed.  One day the office internet was out and I shared my hotspot to my laptop and noticed the count of 2.

You might also have a device lying around that you might have forgotten about, like an iPad in your car near your window or an old phone in your desk drawer.  That happened to me once :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even without ANY wires, cables, or bulky seams...if you're actually on the hotspot setup screen, iOS appears to bump up the count by one (i.e., showing 2 even though only a laptop is connected), then setting it back down to the "true" count once the iOS device is switched to a different screen (i.e., 1 in the example above).

FWIW.